# How to show Wp Latest post video in header

Tags: wordpress, video

I want to show latest post videos in my header(one video) wp. For example I have many posts and some have video in posts then the latest video will display in header.

Anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: you can create a category for videos, then call 1 post of that category in header using the `WP_Query` defined here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: User have some content too in post...

Comment: you must call `the_content()` it will give you video you don't need to have some content if you just need to show the video then I think the php `preg_match` function will do the trick

Comment: I dont want to call the content in header. just want to show video then how it can be possible?